# Do I have to write a lot of boilerplate code if I keep working using Java?

Tags: java, programming-practices

I'm working for a company writing ERP applications. My problem is that I have to write tons of boilerplate code. I came up with ideas to automatize/prevent the drudgery but only some of them were accepted. I have been told by the lead developer that my ideas tend to be go far afield and I should write code everyone can understand.

I had a discussion about this lately and it seems to me that this kind of code ramp is within java's philosophy. I have to write lots of code to achiveve simple things not because it is necessary but because this is the way most of the people at the company think.

Is this universally applicable to most of the companies out there using java or this is just my company's view? Do I have to get used to the drudgery if I keep working for java-based firms?

Comment: "code everyone can understand" - you still havent't tried having to maintain something you cannot understand yet?

Comment: Maybe my phrasing wasn't quite appropriate. For example I used reflection somewhere because this way I had to write only 50 lines of code instead of 300 lines in 3 classes. I wrote comments so everyone can wrap their head around it but I have been told that "reflection is evil".

Comment: and here I thought it is already the Java language itself which forces you to write all that boilerplate code...

Comment: @Frank, depends on what you do.  Guava helps a lot.

Comment: @edem Reflection has a very serious disadvantage, namely that the compiler cannot detect when you do something wrong. Apparently your lead developer has been bitten by this.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, if reflection is used in a dedicated code generator instead of a runtime, there won't be any disadvantages (besides that some underqualified coders would freak out, but as for me, it is a plus).

Comment: @SK-logic except that the compiled code point to the generated code instead of the source used by the code generator.  In my experience this is a serious disadvantage.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, my generated code in debugger always points to a DSL source, not the intermediate code.

Comment: @SK-logic then you generate bytecode and not source code.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: for JVM and CLR - yes, it is easier any way than generating Java or C#. For C/C++ - no, I'm just stuffing the preprocessor `#`-s into a generated code.

Comment: @SK So if I wish to maximize the creative work and kill the drudgery then companies using only java may not be the right choice for me?

Comment: "I'm working for a company writing ERP applications". A lot of enterprise stuff is pretty basic programming. You may have to have a good look round for interesting/creative work, whatever language you use.

Comment: @edem, yes, look for more diverse environments and more entertaining problem domains. There's a lot of fun stuff around.

Comment: @edem: sounds like you should change companies.  Maybe find one that is not using Java.

Comment: Have you considered learning [Python](https://www.python.org/)? I think you might enjoy it more, though jobs using that language are much more scarce than Java.

Answer (score 8):

We are talking about quite different things here. Replacing boilerplate code with a completely different way of doing things, such as reflection, can be hairy. There can indeed be very good reasons against doing this even if it simplifies programming *for you*, such as loss of type safety and security, runtime cost, increased understanding and maintenance cost for others, etc. No idea whether or not that is the case in your situation, but it might well be.

However, simplifying the generation of boilerplate code is quite another thing. If it's repetitive enough that it can be completely automated, then I'd say yes, it absolutely should be automated. There's just too much that can go wrong maintaining such codebases by hand, and just too much effort saved not to do it. And if co-workers can't even understand how a code generator works, then, well, they shouldn't be co-workers in my book.

Comment: Yes my main problem is with code generation.

Comment: Source code generators have the very serious disadvantage that you cannot make compiled code point back to the original but only the generated source.  This makes it harder to work with.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, it only happens if your code generators are stupid. A proper code generator would maintain all the metadata correctly.

Comment: @SK-logic you are aware this is Java, right?  If you generate source you cannot keep the metadata.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, there is no point in generating Java source code. It is counterproductive - someone dumb may try to read or even modify the generated code then. It is much easier to generate bytecode.

Comment: So you have essentially introduced a new homegrown language in your build environment to avoid some boiler plating.  This is most likely what the OP's lead developer mean with "my ideas tend to be go far afield and I should write code everyone can understand."

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, what's wrong with the "homegrown" languages? I believe that *everyone* should use DSLs. There is no single domain which would not benefit from this approach.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, btw., you do not have to implement a full-blown compiler from scratch. Just take a language with metaprogramming capabilities (e.g., Clojure) and build a thin DSL layer on top of it.

Comment: I've been working with clojure for a few months now (on my own) and it looks really nice.

Comment: @SK-logic _any_ non-Java language (DSL or groovy or Clojure or whatever) adds extra complexity to a given solution which must be learned to be productive and which are extra - possibly weak - links in the build chain.  For a team not consisting entirely of experts this alone may be enough disadvantages to not warrant just writing some boilerplate in a language familiar to all already.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, it is plainly *wrong*. Languages are not adding complexity. Languages are there to *reduce* complexity. Imagine, say, General Relativity expressed in a plain arithmetics, without tensor calculus. Imagine dealing with AC circuits without complex arithmetics. Imagine coding everything in assembly, without "adding new languages". Your rant against DSLs is, unfortunately, very typical, and this sort of things is exactly what I do not like in the Java ethos. This is the reason why I won't touch java-only shops with a pole.

Comment: @SK-logic I am not ranting, and my point is valid.   Can we agree that a certain amount of expertise is needed to find and most importantly _fix_ a newly discovered bug in a byte-generator - perhaps even a compiler - for a DSL?  Can we also agree that that amount of expertise is generally not needed for writing Java programs so not all have it?  A team leader may choose to discard that technology simply because of that.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, my point is that it is *easier* to use DSLs than not to use them. And one would need to use *less* brains to fix a problem in a generator rather than debugging a boilerplate pasta bowl. It is exceptionally easy to learn how to generate code, how to write compilers and how to design DSLs. Much easier than all that typical enterprisey patterns and OOP mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: @SK-logic Again you've missed my point.  What if a future maintainer needs to add something new to your DSL, and he/she does not know the implementation language of the DSL compiler?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, no, *you* are missing the whole point of DSLs. Learning languages is 100x times easier than learning stupid, overbloated "frameworks" and "libraries" (especially if they're poisoned with too much OOP). If maintainer knows nothing about the language, maintainer will spend an hour learning this language and solve the problem in much less time than if it were a bloated OOPish boilerplate abomination.

Comment: @SK-logic I believe your assumptions are only valid for expert programmers, and not all teams are solely made of expert programmers.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, not at all. In my practice even non-programmers (DSL end-users) were able to modify the DSL implementation, which itself is implemented in another DSLs, totally declarative, with the visual editing tools. The value of the so called "general purpose" programming languages is excessively overrated.

Answer (score 5):

This question brings this old quote to mind:

> "Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to  debug it. [Brian W. Kernighan]"

In a team environment this would need to be expanded so that if the smartest person on the team writes the cleverest code they can, then the dumbest person onthe team doesn't have any hope of debugging it.

Also just noticed this quote:

> Simplicity is prerequisite for reliability. [Dijkstra]

Comment: What's a point of keeping that dumb person in a team? It's counterproductive.

Comment: In any team, there will be a spread of ability. Just because they are the dumbest person "on the team" doesn't mean they are useless.

Comment: if, because of this dumb person, team decided to stop using practices which otherwise could have improved their performance 10x, then getting rid of that person makes a lot of sense.

Comment: "For every complex problem there is an answer that is clear, simple, and wrong."  -- H.L. Mencken

Comment: In that case they shouldn't have been employed in the first place. But the dumbest person on the team may have an IQ of 150 and be a good programmer, just not as good as teh best guy on the team.

Comment: Maybe it did not turn out when they interviewed that person.

Comment: I see the point.

Comment: @Jaydee, there is a stupidity threshold, above which *everyone* would understand all the basic simple things, like DSLs, compilation, interpretation, reflection, etc.

Comment: Perhaps all the individual bits, but from my experience, some programmers take pride in producing the most inpenatrable code they can and they then say, "but it's obvious". There are ways of combining and using even common things that take a lot of figuring out especially if you are trying to sort something our several years later when the person that wrote it has gone.

Comment: @Jaydee, DSLs are the most powerful thing out there to fight this attitude efficiently. You can't be a smart ass with a DSL - you're always supposed to design a language as simple and obvious as possible, otherwise there is no point in DSLs at all.

Comment: Something about removing the dumbest member of the team seems illogical: `function removeDumbest(team){
var dIndex = 0;
var dIQ;
for(var i=0; i < team.length; i++){
if(dIQ == null || dIQ < team[i].iq){
dIQ = team[i].iq;
dIndex = i;
}
}
team.splice(dIndex, 1);
removeDumbest(team);
}`

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe that the use of 'boiler plate' code is related to a particular language, but rather that it is a design decision. For whatever reasons, the company you are currently working for has made that choice, possibly in relation to ease of maintenance or facilitating the operational support of the applications. 'Reflection is evil' is just a reflection on those reasons, an easy mantra to remember and put in practice.

Comment: No, it is language-related. Boilerplate code is unavoidable with *any* language that does not support proper metaprogramming. Even languages like Haskell would suffer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can have boilerplate code in software written in any language. It's not java specific. I've written and worked with big java applications which had almost zero boilerplate code.

Like in every other software, there may be some simple boilerplate code here and there. But usually, it's small and it's not really a problem to type the couple of extra lines, nor does it harm readability. On the other hand, it may help debugging, maintenance, etc...

That being said, the aim of all source code should be to strive for simplicity and ease of understanding. *If* the boilerplate is excessive *and* you have a much simpler solution, leading to more readable, maintainable, understandable code, then, by all means, do it. Show it to your superior, that it's simpler, safer, less code, etc. and if it's indeed that obvious, his decision should be obvious as well.

Now, on the other hand, if you want to make an super complicated inflexible unsafe construct just to save a couple of boilerplate lines, then, I agree with your boss. It may be a source of more complexity then it tries to solve. Remember that you don't code for yourself, you code for others.

Answer (score 0):

It's one thing to invent a new language that gets translated into the target language (think coffeescript->javascript) and a completely different thing to have a generator that only creates the first version of a source file.

The former is expensive and difficult to make, and should be left to people who know how to design and implement languages.

The later is helpful in environments where lots of redundant boilerplate code is required, and usually it's not very difficult to design and make. Using such a tool generates boilerplate code that looks like it was written by hand, just a bit more consistent and typo-free. Once generated, the source file is further worked on, edited, adapted, extended etc. The input-file for the generator is one-off; no attempt is made to allow round-trips etc.

To answer your question: Go for the second option, don't bother trying the first.

Comment: Generating source code and then editing it may be necessary sometimes, but it can lead to a maintenance nightmare with lots of repetitive code.  I think it's better to use generated code and handwritten code together, but in different files, without ever touching the generated code by hand.  This way you can always re-generate it when it needs to grow.

Comment: Philip: If that is possible, sure, keep the generated code untouched. Anyway, if the only choice is between "generate" and "write by hand", I'd choose "generate" all the time.

Comment: *Everyone* have to learn how do design and implement languages. Because it is extremely easy, and it's the biggest single possible productivity boost for any possible programming domain.

Comment: SK-logic: You are assuming competent programmers. Go read Codinghorror.com. ;-)

Comment: @ammoQ, it is at least much easier than OOP and than coding in the "general purpose" imperative languages. And since these things are pervasively mainstream, everyone from that mainstream background should be more than capable of implementing and designing DSLs.